# Div to disable on click and enable again if another div is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a div that upon click will show a modal, once the modal is then seen, user clicks a button in the modal and it closes.

I want to prevent the user to click again on the initial div, they will only be able to click it if they have clicked another different div.

Here is my code with the most "similar"/pseudo code of what I want to achieve:

HTML

```
<div>
<div class="container-what-we-offer">
 <p>It's what we offer</p>
</div>
<div class="container-are-you-sure">
  <p>
   Are you sure?
  </p>
</div>
<div class="modal">
  <p>
   This is what we offer modal
  </p>
  <button>Happy with the offer</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(".container-are-you-sure").click(function(e) {
    showModal();
    if(modal has been shown && button happy with the offer has been clicked){
    dontShowModalAgainUponClickingMe();
} else if (container-what-we-offer has been clicked){
    showModal()
}
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You could add a global variable to check if the modal as already been opened, and another one if the button has been clicked

Comment: thanks @polypode and how do I then stop the function if the button has been clicked and modal has been opened?

Comment: You can either add an `if` statement to check the two vars and do nothing. Or you could remove the event listener entierely

Answer (score 1):

You can set a variable and use that to control if the button have been click and if the modal shall be seen or not.

```
var modalButtonClicked = false;
$(".container-are-you-sure").click(function(e) {

  if (!modalButtonClicked) {
    showModal();
  }
});

function showModal() {
  $(".modal")
    .show();
}

$(".modal button").click(function() {
  modalButtonClicked = true;
  $(".modal").hide();
});
```

**demo**

```js
var modalButtonClicked = false;
$(".container-are-you-sure").click(function(e) {

  if (!modalButtonClicked) {
    showModal();
  }
});

function showModal() {
  $(".modal")
    .show();
}

$(".modal button").click(function() {
  modalButtonClicked = true;
  $(".modal").hide();
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="container-what-we-offer">
    <p>It's what we offer</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container-are-you-sure">
    <p>
      Are you sure?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal">
    <p>
      This is what we offer modal
    </p>
    <button>Happy with the offer</button>
  </div>
</div>
```